# Trying to access route.params in react native stack navigator v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to access the props.route.params.data information from the react navigation route prop, however when I try to output it on the screen it just says TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating `props.routes.params`). I know I have correctly followed the path to that `data` object because I console.log it on the console and it outputs that data. However when I want to put put it on the user interface it gives me that error. Been searchong online but no one has the same issue, maybe because the way to get the params using react stack navigator v5 is by route.params, and v5 came outa couple of months ago. So I will post my code below along with the console.log screen, the error message, and also the object that I am picking from. Thank you!

```
// App.js

import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { View , StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import About from "./screens/About";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import PokeDetails from "./screens/PokeDetails"
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';



const App =()=> {

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="PokeDetails" component={PokeDetails}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
})
  


export default App;



// Home.js


import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text , Button, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/GlobalStyles";
import PokeDetails from "./PokeDetails";
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';





class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20`)
            .then((res)=> res.json())
            .then((response)=> {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: response.results,
                })
                console.log("RESPONSE",response)
                console.log("RESPONSE.RESSSULTS",response.results)
            })
           
    }

    render() {
       
        const showIndicator = this.state.isLoading == true ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> : null;
        return(
            <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
                <View style={GlobalStyles.activityIndicator}>{showIndicator}</View>
                <FlatList 
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                    numColumns={1}
                    data={this.state.dataSource} 
                    renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', 
                    {data:"hello"})}>
                        <PokeDetails  imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    }/>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("About")} title="Go to about"/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

    
export default Home;


// PokeDetails.js

import React from "react";
import { View, Text , Image, Button} from "react-native";
import {GlobalStyles} from "../styles/GlobalStyles";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';



const PokeDetails =(props)=> {
   
    console.log(props)
    console.log(props.route.params.data, "PROPSSSSSSSSSSS");
    
        return(
            <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>  
                    <Image source={{uri: props.imageUrl}} style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
                    <Text>{props.route.params.data}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    

}
    


export default PokeDetails;
```

[image][image]

Comment: The error is because you are loading pokedetails.js inside your home.js the props with the route will only be accessible when you navigate to the pokedetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error because you are pokedetails in your home screen, you can get the data props only if you navigate to pokedetails screen, the thing you can do something like this:

change your Home.js like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text , Button, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import PokeDetails from "./Pokedetails";
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';





class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20`)
            .then((res)=> res.json())
            .then((response)=> {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: response.results,
                })
                console.log("RESPONSE",response)
                console.log("RESPONSE.RESSSULTS",response.results)
            })

    }

    render() {

        const showIndicator = this.state.isLoading == true ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> : null;
        return(
            <View>
                <View>{showIndicator}</View>
                <FlatList 
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
                    numColumns={1}
                    data={this.state.dataSource} 
                    renderItem={({item})=> 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', 
                    {data:"hello", imageUrl:`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`})}>
                        <PokeDetails  imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    }/>
                <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("About")} title="Go to about"/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


export default Home;
```

Here iam just passing imageUrl also for reference purpose.

change your pokedetails.js some thing like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text , Image, Button} from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';



const PokeDetails =(props)=> {
console.log("props is",props);
if(props.navigation == undefined)
{
    return(
        <View>  
        <Image source={{uri: props.imageUrl}} style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
        <Text>{props.name}</Text>
</View>
    )
}
else{
    return(
        <View>  
                <Image source={{uri: props.route.params.imageUrl}} style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
                <Text>{props.route.params.data}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
}

export default PokeDetails;
```

Here iam just adding a if condition to check whether the screen is loaded is navigated from another screen.

when the Homescreen loaded it will be something like this:

[image]

On clicking bulbassor you will be navigating to the pokedetails screen where here iam showing the details you are sending through navigation:

[image]

Hope this helps!